# couldnt generate frequency and sinewave using ad9833 with atmega2560

Tags: spi

I am using 4 AD9833, in which the 4 fsync signals are sent from atmega2560. I want to generate different frequencies from all the 4 AD9833, if I program it, I am getting some frequencies in 2 port pins,  I could not change the frequency .. please help

Answer (score 0):

For the Atmega2560, you may want to look up "SPI" programming at here:

http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega2560

Using the SPI library, u can then issue command to the AD9833 via SPI interfacing.   For details lookup page 2 here:

http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD9833.pdf

(and page 15 above described the details on specifying the frequencies).

More information on SPI programming for Atmel is here:  http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0943.pdf

For SPI example for Arduino:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YE0wnom_7As
http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BarometricPressureSensor  (look for SPI.begin(), SPI.transfer() etc).

For the SPI library specification:

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI